# dbforge mysql studio, how to edit a broken view?

Tags: mysql, dbforge

Using dbforge mysql studio, I edit the columns of a table, and whoops, this breaks some views, but now when I try to open them to edit them, I get a "references invalid columns" error,

and it refuses to let me edit the sql of the view.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After renaming column in table, view becomes invalid. dbForge uses 'SHOW CREATE VIEW' command to get object's definition, and it throws this error.

I can suggest you to alter view in a SQL Document, e.g. -

```
ALTER VIEW view1 AS SELECT column1, column2, column3_new_name FROM table1;
```

It should fix view.

Also, you can write requests in our [support system](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/support.html).

Comment: The most likely cause of the trouble is that the dbForge Studio version is outdated. Please upgrade to the latest version, and the problem should not persist.